# How can I cache output response stream in ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, caching

I want cache output stream in asp.net. 
For example I want cache the html result of a grid after rendering.
because of my grid filled by some parameters, I can't use a cached usercontrol. I can't cache page so.
Now I cache DB result, but asp .net process in my pages is high and I want to pass it.

How can I do it?

Comment: You probably want to investigate why the ASP.NET processing in your pages is high. How long will things be cached for? If it's a long time, consider building your grid in a different way. Also, if it's being requested a lot, why are you getting so many page hits? Is it because really you need some Ajax to update the grid rather than insisting on a reload?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use (Page Output )[`Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178597%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: I have over 200,000 page view per day. In my case, for each product I select merchandises and view chart of history of each merchandise price. I can't cache all of page because I have user accounting places in my pages.

Comment: I found a solution. I RenderControl() my grid and save the HTML result in a cache control. What's your idea?